# Externalize bootstrap servers configuration

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Say we were to use [confluent-kafka-dotnet](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/), ProducerConfig takes an array of Kafka broker addresses in its BootstrapServers property.

We could put those addresses in web.config, but assuming we're using a microservices architecture, if we were to change the Kafka cluster configuration (such as adding new brokers), we'd have to update a lot of web.config files.

I'm curious how others have solved this problem.

Comment: You can use consul (https://www.consul.io/) or similar solutions

Comment: you should also restart producers after you make this kind of change. AFAK producers are not being aware when bootstrap server list has changed.

Comment: @jit If new brokers are added, that doesn't mean new partitions are, so therefore existing data isn't moved and requests would not be required to go to new machines

Comment: @cricket_007 what if old brokers goes down and you are only left with the newly added broker?

Comment: @jit Then you'll still get client connection errors because partitions hosted on those machines are entirely offline

Comment: @cricket_007 if unclean leader election is set to true you would benefit the newly added broker in that case and this is what people call high availability. You can not just ignore the newly added brokers on producer side. this is so wrong for HA.

Comment: @jit Refer [to the documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_cluster_expansion) about cluster expansion -- *these new servers will not automatically be assigned any data partitions, so unless partitions are moved to them they won't be doing any work until new topics are created. So usually when you add machines to your cluster you will want to migrate some existing data to these machines*

Comment: @cricket_007 if you are adding a new broker there is no doubt that you are doing this for data replication across nodes and you mostly increment RF by 1,2 etc according to number of brokers you added to cluster. Why someone adds a new borker to a cluster? Of course for the sake of HA and Replication.

Comment: @jit Starting from the top, I was referring to *"producers are not being aware when bootstrap server list has changed"* -- And I think they might be aware because the Controller knows the full list of brokers at any time. The question was saying *"such as adding new brokers"*, to which I was saying that new brokers would have no data that existing producers can use ***without manual intervention*** to reassign existing partitions or expand a topic onto them... That was all I was getting at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than reading from a config file, I would suggest reading from an environment variable like `BOOTSTRAP_SERVER`, for example.

If you added a new broker to the existing cluster, then you don't have to worry about changing anything as long as your initial configs have at least 3 other healthy brokers listed - the rest will be *bootstrapped* by the Controller, and returned to client, hence the name of the property. You may need to bounce the app to get a new bootstrapping, or you can tweak the value of `metadata.max.age.ms` to re-force a refresh faster.

As mentioned in the comments, Consul is popular for dynamic service discovery, so you would then just have one entry for `kafka.consul`, and via DNS, it'll pick up any healthy service registered under `kafka`

Answer (score 1):

you can store kafka details from any store repecting environment.
all you need to do is change this store detail for specific environment and restart your server if you starting producer on bootstrap otherwise this step can be skipped.

we are storing in vault.

http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/production/kafka
{
host1:9091,host2:9091
}
http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/staging/kafka
{
host:9091
}

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. "We are storing in vault." Is vault the name of a software package?

Comment: @Marcel Hashicorp Vault, yes

Comment: However, the list of brokers is not a "secret", so really Consul KV or other REST API makes more sense to store this information

Comment: agree , the reason we did to avoid unauthorized person to get cluster information . only prod ops knows cluster details and applications with vault token can only connect to cluster.